# Create a dynamic radar for an android application

Tags: javascript, android

I would like to create a dynamic radar for an android application in android studio something that looks like this :

http://jsbin.com/AMag/2/edit?html,css,output

How could I do this ?

Comment: Show us some code.  Maybe you could get the part where you draw a circle and someone will help you draw a line.  Ohh that's a cool looking radar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start point. Create a custom view like this and add it to a LinearLayout.

```
class RadarBlip {
    float x;
    float y;

    public void setX (float x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public Float getX() {
        return x;
    }
    ....
}

private class RadarView extends View {

    List<RadarBlip> mRadarBlips;

    public TimerViewContentView(Context context, List<RadarBlip> radarBlips, currentRadarAngle) {
        super(context);
        setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mRadarBlips = radarBlips;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mRadarBlips.size(); i++) {
            blipPaint.setAlpha(...do geometry...);
            canvas.drawCircle(mRadarBlips.get(i).getX(), mRadarBlips.get(i).getY(), radius, blipPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawArc(oval, currentRadarAngle, currentRadarAngle - 10, false, radarPaint);
    }
}
```

You then want to call the view in a Timer. Something like:

```
    new CountDownTimer(timeRemaining, 15) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            float radarAngle = ((long)millisUntilFinished)%((long)timeForRevolution) * 360f;
            RadarView mRadarView = new RadarView(MyActivity.this,radarPointsArray,radarAngle);
            radarLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            radarTimerLayout.addView(mRadarView);
            timeRemaining = millisUntilFinished;
        }
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    }.start();
```

Thinking about it might be better to use ObjectAnimator from NineOldAndroids instead of a Timer. Though ObjectAnimator has a tendency to never stop and drain the battery unless you add a function to stop it.